# cornerRadius causes long load time in iOS 10

Tags: ios, calayer, xcode8, ios10, cornerradius

I have a problem with my App. I have a View with 25 Buttons with changed cornerRadius. Since iOS 10 it takes about 5-6 seconds till this View loads.
Here is the relevant code:

```
- (void)setupTiles {
 for (TileButton *btn in tiles_btn) {
  btn.alpha = 0.0;
  btn.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
  btn.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
  [btn layoutIfNeeded];
  bin.layer.cornerRadius = btn.frame.size.width*0.3;
 }
 [self colorTilesWithArray:currentTileColors];
}
```

When i remove the following lines, is loads the view instantly:

```
[btn layoutIfNeeded];
bin.layer.cornerRadius = btn.frame.size.width*0.3;
```

The Buttons are grouped in an outlet collection, in case that's necessary to know.

Does anybody have a solution?
Thanks in advance!

Nico

[Image 1: This takes about 5-6 seconds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIzwY.png)

[Image 2: This is the View that will be loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2Zcg.png)

TileButton.h-File:

```
@interface TileButton : UIButton

@property (nonatomic) int colorMode;

+ (UIColor *)blue;
+ (UIColor *)red;
+ (UIColor *)green;
+ (UIColor *)yellow;
+(UIColor *)colorForColorCode:(int)colorCode;
-(int)colorMode;

@end
```

TileButton.m-File:

```
@implementation TileButton
- (instancetype)init {
self = [super init];
if (self) {
    self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.width*0.3;
}
return self;
}

+(UIColor *)blue {
return [UIColor colorWithRed:41.0/255.0 green:161.0/255.0 blue:255.0/255.0 alpha:1];
}

+(UIColor *)red {
return [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:71.0/255.0 blue:109.0/255.0 alpha:1];
}

+(UIColor *)green {
return [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0/255.0 green:185.0/255.0 blue:30.0/255.0 alpha:1];
} 

+(UIColor *)yellow {
return [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:198.0/255.0 blue:26.0/255.0 alpha:1];
} 

+(UIColor *)colorForColorCode:(int)colorCode {
switch (colorCode) {
    case 1:
        return [TileButton blue];
        break;
    case 2:
        return [TileButton red];
        break;
    case 3:
        return [TileButton green];
        break;
    case 4:
        return [TileButton yellow];
        break;
    default:
        return [UIColor blackColor];
        break;
}
}

-(int)colorMode {
if (CGColorEqualToColor(self.backgroundColor.CGColor, [TileButton blue].CGColor))
    return 1;
else if (CGColorEqualToColor(self.backgroundColor.CGColor, [TileButton red].CGColor))
    return 2;
else if (CGColorEqualToColor(self.backgroundColor.CGColor, [TileButton green].CGColor))
    return 3;
else if (CGColorEqualToColor(self.backgroundColor.CGColor, [TileButton yellow].CGColor))
    return 4;
else
    return -1;
}

@end
```

Comment: You _should_ delete `layoutIfNeeded`. That is a useless and terrible thing to say.

Comment: Along with removing the call to `layoutIfNeeded` everything in that for loop could probably be moved to the `TileButton` constructor.

Comment: Can you try with image background instead of setting corner radius?

Comment: I would guess that there is some kind of cycle where calling layoutIfNeeded is invoking layoutSubviews which is then invoking layoutIfNeeded.  You can find out if that is indeed the case by putting a print statement in layoutSubviews. Also try using setNeedsLayout instead of layoutIfNeeded.  layoutIfNeeded tells the system to do the layout right now while setNeedsLayout just tells the system to flag the view  to recalculate sometime before the next redraw. You can also try not calling LayoutIfNeeded on each view; call it on the superview at the end of the loop; it will cascade to the children.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answers. I used `layoutIfNeeded` because without it, it does not show any Button since iOS 10. But I will try `setNeedsLayout`. Also I will try to move this into the constructor. @HMHero I wanted to try to make these Button "Resolution-independent", so I don't have to make an image for every screen size

Comment: Okay, I have tested these things out:

`[btn setNeedsLayout];
btn.layer.cornerRadius = btn.frame.size.width*0.3;`
does not work. The buttons do not show up at all :(

`[self.view setNeedsLayout];` before or after the for-loop doesn’t work too. The Buttons also do not show up.

@werm098 : Did you mean this?:
`- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.width*0.3;
    }
    return self;
}`

Comment: @NG_Loc without seeing more of the TileButton class that does look like what I was thinking. Did that help?

Comment: @werm098 I updated my first post with the Code

Comment: @werm098 The way I did it didn't work. Maybe because I am not creating these Buttons programmatically? I am "creating" them through the interface Builder

Comment: Ahh, ok. Then try putting the `bin.layer.cornerRadius = btn.frame.size.width*0.3;` in the TileButton`-awakeFromNib` method. That method is called when the class is loaded from interface builder.

Comment: @werm098 Nice Man! It works!!! Thank you very much. How can I mark your answer as the solution?

Comment: @NG_Loc I've added a complete answer (not on a Mac to double check if my syntax is correct though so let me know if i need to edit anything). I'm glad it works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are creating the buttons in Interface Builder you will need to set the `cornerRadius` in the `awakeFromNib` method. It should look something like this:

```
@implementation TileButton
-(void) awakeFromNib {
     [super awakeFromNib];
     self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.width*0.3;
}
```

https://developer.apple.com/reference/objectivec/nsobject/1402907-awakefromnib

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you set the corner radius outside the for loop?

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)]; // set your frame here
bin.layer.cornerRadius = btn.frame.size.width*0.3; // width stays the same, set it here
for (TileButton *btn in tiles_btn) {
    btn.alpha = 0.0;
    btn.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    btn.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
    // you need to set the button frame here
    btn.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,0,0);
    [btn layoutIfNeeded];
}
[self colorTilesWithArray:currentTileColors];
```

Comment: Because there are 25 Buttons in an Outlet Collection an only in the for-loop I can set the cornerRadius for every Button :/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that TileButton is a subclass of UIButton, on initialization, you can set the TileButton to have your custom color, width, and corner radius. That way all of your buttons already have the specified customization on button creation.